# How to stop the activity indicator in swift after a condition is met?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, uitableview

I have declared a UIActivityIndicatorView as a computed property in extension of my model. I have a method configureCell where I'm trying to use activity indicator as a subview of an imageView. Here I'm able to position the indicator on certain condition but am not able to do any changes on it later. E.g I am not able to stop the activity indicator, not able to change the color, not able to even hide it.

```
extension TranscationModel: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{

 var activityIN: UIActivityIndicatorView {
    var act = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
    act.color = UIColor.redColor()
    act.hidden = false
    act.startAnimating()
    return act
}

func configureTransactionCell(cell : TransactionCell?, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if transaction.tid == "Something" {
        activityIN.color = UIColor.greenColor() //Even this doesn't work
        activityIN.center = cell.imgTransactionBill.center
        cell.imgTransactionBill.addSubview(activityIN)
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(10 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             activityIN.stopAnimating() //Not working
             activityIN.hidden = true   //Not working
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined `activityIN` as computed variable. Any time when you call it, you get completely new instance. Look at `activityIN` var as at convenience initializer of `UIActivityIndicatorView`. If you only need activity for ten seconds, edit your func like this:

```
func configureTransactionCell(cell : TransactionCell?, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if transaction.tid == "Something" {
        let weakActivityIndicator = activityIN
        weakActivityIndicator.color = UIColor.greenColor()
        weakActivityIndicator.center = cell.imgTransactionBill.center
        cell.imgTransactionBill.addSubview(weakActivityIndicator)
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(10 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             weakActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
             weakActivityIndicator.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

But usually you need to keep reference to instance that you get from this initializer. Define `UIActivityIndicatorView` stored property in your `TransactionCell` class.

Assume that `TransactionCell` class have declaration

```
var cellActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

then you can edit your func like this

```
func configureTransactionCell(cell : TransactionCell?, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if transaction.tid == "Something" {
        cell.cellActivityIndicator = activityIN
        cell.cellActivityIndicator.color = UIColor.greenColor()
        cell.cellActivityIndicator.center = cell.imgTransactionBill.center
        cell.imgTransactionBill.addSubview(cell.cellActivityIndicator)
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(10 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             cell.cellActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
             cell.cellActivityIndicator.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shadow Of .